# problems with arrays from firebase to kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to get this array for a few days, to start another search from each of the elements of the array, but I can't find a way to get the array, I've tried some ways but it is only obtained as a position, and I haven't found lots of official documentation.

Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: So you only want to get those three ids that exist within the "favorites_id" array?

Comment: yeah it's the only thing i want to get

Comment: Once you [get the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), getting fields from that document should not be the hard part. Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Is there something in code you already have tried? Please also respond with @.

Comment: Sorry for not answering before, but this is what I have tried, but I am not going through the position one by one by the for https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/828998884729815040/828999080884699146/unknown.png @AlexMamo

Comment: So I see you already have the content of that array, right?

Comment: @juancarlos_nr,  as Alex Mamo said, I guess you have solved your issue, as in the image you posted you get the list of ids that you were looking for, right?